# Nexus - storage folder missing

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

Basically we already had a nexus server configured but now we do not have access to that server for some reason. Now, I have the repository folder which contains all the dependency I will require to upload it in new nexus server.

So, for this I can upload each dependency one by one using command line or by Nexus UI. But I have multiple dependencies So I am looking for alternative

So, I found this solution

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410676/2741693)

And I am following 3rd suggestion but I am not getting which access I will needed. Because I do not see such directory in my local machine.

I have extracted `nexus-3.12.1-01` setup in my windows machine.

Where can I found this folder?

Comment: Starting with Nexus3 there are no directories anymore on the hard drive cause the format with Nexus3 has changed (blog storage)..there is an upload REST API which can used for scripts https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api#ComponentsAPI-UploadComponent

Comment: Does the repo folder contain blobs or does it contain components?